# how to send commands from a computer to another computer in CentOS?

Tags: python, centos

I need to send a command from a computer to another computer (both running in CentOS). It has to be automated so I need to make a script or a program to do this.

Let's say for example, COMPUTER A will send this command to COMPUTER B

> python insertDB.py

when COMPUTER B receives this, It needs to automatically run the command sent by COMPUTER A.

how do I do it? Is it possible to do it in python in a very simple way?

thanks

Comment: Check out fabric! EDIT: rpyc seems to fit your needs better (as HollyStyles suggests)

Comment: Are these all shell commands like your example? If so, why not simply run the remote command with ssh?

Comment: I prefer using the SSH commands, the only problem is that it doesn't allow the password to be put in the same line with the user name, host name and the commands. I realized that sshpass could be the solution to this problem however I can't install it. $yum install sshpass is not working. Do you know what's wrong with the command that im using? I'll be searching for the correct command to  be able to install it, If it still wont work, Ill use rpyc.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? [RPyC : Transparent, Symmetric Distributed Computing](https://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I tried to use RPyc but Im stuck in the installation part. 'easy_install rpyc' isnt working in centos, 'yum install rpyc' is not working also. Do you know the command to install? thanks

Comment: shrug, according to this https://github.com/tomerfiliba/rpyc/blob/master/site/install.rst easy_install should work. "isnt working" ??? come on, you should know better than that. What *exactly* isn't working?

Comment: it says, easy_install : command not found . It's been a week since I started using Centos, my knowledge is not enough. I could not find any articles discussing (different way) the step by step installation of rpyc.

Comment: I think i know what the problem is. easy_install should be installed as well. That's why it kept on giving me the "command not found" error.

Comment: I think easy_install is part of Python's setuptools. Command not found can also mean it's not in your path.

Comment: yes. that's what I did. I followed the instructions here  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads and it worked! thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [pexpect](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pexpect/). Although rpyc probably is a better choice.